# How to read adb response from jar?

Tags: java, android, adb

I am trying to batch some apps installations and I want to do it app by app.
I am trying to get the adb command response into my java program but I don't manage to understand why I don't get anything from an `InputStream`!

Here is my test code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class main_adbStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("platform-tools\\adb.exe -s " + args[0] + ":5555 install -r " + args[1]);   // + " >> " + SBCWLogger.getFileHandlerName()

            //add installation verification
            InputStream is = pro.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
            //verification done
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I found this answer which is not working, and I do not manage to use `pro.getInputStream()` properly either.

I also tried most of the [answers from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/309424/how-to-read-convert-an-inputstream-into-a-string-in-java) but none of those I tested worked. I successfully read the errors when I don't connect or when the install fails, but not the informational messages as `Success` at the end of an install. And that is what I want.

**EDIT**: the code below is working thanks to Onix' answer.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class main_adbStreamTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            Process pro = new ProcessBuilder("platform-tools\\adb.exe", "-s",args[0], "install", "-r", args[1]).start();

            //add installation verification
            InputStream is = pro.getInputStream();
            int i = 0;
            while( (i = is.read() ) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char)i);
            }
            //verification done
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

And to get the famous `Success`, just write the stream to a file and read the last row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Process process = new ProcessBuilder("Full path to adb", "-s", args[0], "install", "-r", args[1]).start();    
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
```